# Reset input value in onClick event of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know this is Simple, but it is little confusing to me :(

Why the input value in the below case is not getting reset.

```
handleReset() {
  this.setState({ data: "" });
}

<button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
```

However, when I use inline way in the `onClick` event, I'm able to reset the input value.

```
<button onClick={()=>{ this.setState({ data: "" });}}>Reset</button>
```

I created a working example using [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/vYYWEzG). Could anyone please guide me where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to bind the `handleReset()` function to the class or use an arrow function. The scope of `this` changes otherwise.

Try with an arrow function (which binds the scope):

```
handleReset = () => {
  this.setState({ data: "" });
}
```

5 more examples at:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/

**UPDATE:**

Small library that automatically binds methods to their class instances.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-bind

Answer (score 1):

Recommended approach

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
}

handleReset() {
  this.setState({ data: "" });
}

<button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
```